# V8 memory management for argument's return value

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, v8

I'm confused by how V8 manages its memory.

**Issue:**

I understand basically V8 uses Handle to refer to the real instances in memory, and with HandleScope, all the local handles  can be managed automatically and easily. But I can't undetstand why  FunctionCallbackInfo doesn't use Handle to keep the return value:

```
void MyMethod(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) 
{
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);

    cout<<"totally "<<args.Length()<<" arguments"<<endl;

    int result = AddOpeation(args[0]->Int32Value(), args[1]->Int32Value());
    char *s = new char [10];
    ZeroMemory(s, 10);
    _itoa_s(result, s, 9, 10);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, s)); // I'm confused by this line of code !!!
    delete [] s;
}
```

Here is the implementation of **FunctionCallbackInfo::GetReturnValue**

```
template<typename T>
ReturnValue<T> FunctionCallbackInfo<T>::GetReturnValue() const {
    return ReturnValue<T>(&implicit_args_[kReturnValueIndex]);
}
```

And here is the implementation of **ReturnValue::Set**:

```
template<typename T>
template<typename S>
void ReturnValue<T>::Set(const Handle<S> handle) {
   TYPE_CHECK(T, S);
   if (V8_UNLIKELY(handle.IsEmpty())) {
      *value_ = GetDefaultValue();
   } else {
   *value_ = *reinterpret_cast<internal::Object**>(*handle);
}
```

Here is the definition of **ReturnValue::value_**：

```
  ...
  V8_INLINE void SetInternal(internal::Object* value) { *value_ = value; }
  V8_INLINE internal::Object* GetDefaultValue();
  V8_INLINE explicit ReturnValue(internal::Object** slot);
  internal::Object** value_;
```

**Question:**

Back to my code - the function MyMethod, since **ReturnValue::value_** is not a handle, will it be safe to access ReturnValue::value_ once the HandleScope is destroyed?

**My guess:**

If I created two classes' instances like this:

```
HandleScope s0(...);
LocalHandle<FunctionCallbackInfo> h0 = ...;    
...
{
    HandleScope s1(...);
    LocalHandle<MyType> h1 = ...;
    h0.ptr = *h1; // Suppose ptr is a member field defined in FunctionCallbackInfo
}
```

S1 will be destroyed before S0, at that moment, because s0 is still alive, so does h0, and *h1 is a member field of h0, so V8 GC will not cleanup the memory referenced by *h1 or h0.ptr.

Is my guess reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

`v8::HandleScope` will destroy all local handles on scope exit. I suppose there is no way to notify the handle scope which handle is the result and shouldn't be destroyed. But `v8::EscapableHandleScope` allows to do this:

```
void MyMethod(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) 
{
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    EscapableHandleScope scope(isolate);

    int result = AddOpeation(args[0]->Int32Value(), args[1]->Int32Value());
    char s[10];
    _itoa_s(result, s, 9, 10);
    Local<String> result = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, s);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(scope.Escape(result));
}
```

Please refer to the bottom of section [Handles and Garbage Collection](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#handles-and-garbage-collection) in V8 guide.

Comment: according to sample code in node.js official website [link](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), HandleScope is used:

`void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  HandleScope scope(isolate);
  args.GetReturnValue().Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world"));
}`.

Comment: I think this answer is correct for newer V8. Node most likely uses old V8 version that doesn't have `EscapableHandleScope`.